# How to get List of DayOfWeek from between two DayOfWeeks

Tags: java, datetime, dayofweek, date

I want to get the list of DayOfWeeks, between two DayOfWeeks.

For example,

```
Input1: DayOfWeek.MONDAY
Input2: DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY
```

And output should be list

```
[DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY,
DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY]
```

Is Java providing any Api to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get days using [DayOfWeek.values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#values--) and then use `filter` to filter the days between `MONDAY` and `WEDNESDAY`

```
List<DayOfWeek> days = Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values())
            .filter(day -> day.getValue() >= DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue()
                    && day.getValue() <= DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(days);
```

Comment: This is a great solution, one caveat worth mentioning is that the reference to DayOfWeek#values creates another copy of the DayOfWeek enum elements to ensure immutability for the underlying array.

Answer (score 2):

### Crossing the week boundary

The other answers are good (I particularly like Basil Bourque’s [`EnumSet` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61301292/642706)). They all seem to presuppose (1) that your two input days are in the same week, and (2) that the week begins on Monday as the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum does. Now what if inputs were Friday and Monday, wouldn’t we want *Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday*? What if the user in the USA and expects that Sunday and Tuesday yields *Sunday, Monday, Tuesday*? Sunday is the first day of the week there (and in some other places too).

I think that taking these possibilities into account there is no better solution than a classical loop.

```
    DayOfWeek input1 = DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
    DayOfWeek input2 = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;

    List<DayOfWeek> range = new ArrayList<>(7);
    DayOfWeek currentDow = input1;
    range.add(currentDow);
    while (! currentDow.equals(input2)) {
        currentDow = currentDow.plus(1);
        range.add(currentDow);
    }

    System.out.println(range);
```

Output:

> [FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY]

Since I am using a list rather than a set, the days come in order. Fortunately the [`plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#plus(long)) method has cyclic overflow: `SUNDAY.plus(1)` yields [`MONDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY), the first enum member.

### Not crossing the week boundary

If it’s a requirement that you are *not* crossing into the following week (from Sunday to Monday), you should check that your inputs fulfill the requirement and then use one of the other answers. Example check:

```
    if (input1.getValue() > input2.getValue()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Inputs muct be in chronological order within the same Monday-based week");
    }
```

Comment: `Crossing the week boundary` and `Since I am using a list rather than a set, the days come in order.` are really good points.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can achieve it. There may be a better way. You create a Stream of Integer values where the start is the first day and the last is the last day + 1. Then map the DayOfWeek object in respect to the day value.

```java
        DayOfWeek monday = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;

        DayOfWeek wednesday = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;

        List<DayOfWeek> days = IntStream.range(monday.getValue(), wednesday.getValue() + 1)
                .mapToObj(DayOfWeek::of)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output

```
[MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY]
```

Comment: Or `IntStream.rangeClosed()` so you don't need to add 1?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY )
```

## `EnumSet.range`

[`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) is an implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) optimized for working with enum objects.

[`EnumSet.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#range(E,E)) creates a subset of the enum’s objects in the order of their definition. For [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), that order is Monday-Sunday, per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

The range is fully-closed, meaning both the beginning and the ending are inclusive.

```
Set<DayOfWeek> set = EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );
```

> set.toString(): [MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY]

If your problem domain uses an order of days different than Monday-Sunday, see the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61301292/642706)

If you really need a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) rather than a `Set`, convert. Feed the set to the constructor of a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`.

```
List< DayOfWeek > dows = new ArrayList<>( set );
```